# markdown, display <word> as a link?

Tags: support, markdown

How to display the following as a link?

```
[<TextView>][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html
```

The following shows it as a `<TextView>`, not as a link

```
[`<TextView>`][1] 

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html
```

---

Comment: How does it not display as a link? It takes on the link color just like any other link does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

[<TextView>](http://example.com)

markdown:

```
[&lt;TextView&gt;](http://example.com)
```